# Problem building sphinx documentation with a project located in Filr (micro focus)

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm able to build normally my documentation using sphinx when my project is located, let's say on my desktop or elsewhere.

However, I have all my files backup in Filr (micro focus). That is what we use at my work. Having recently moved my project to this backup system, I noticed that the sphinx cannot build it anymore. I have to perform the test elsewhere, and it works.
Of course I have double checked the path and files name, but nothing seems to work.

For your information, I can access Filr off-line as well as, since it synchronises automatically.

Here is the basic error I obtain. It seems that the source file can't be found eventhough it is just there:

```
cd "C:\Users\antdu953\Filr\My Files\WAVE ENERGY\RESEARCH\MODELLING\xModel\docs"
make html
```

Output:

```
Application error:
Cannot find source directory (C:\Users\antdu953\Filr\My Files\WAVE ENERGY\RESEARCH\MODELLING\xModel\docs\source)
```

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is to merge all source directories as a preliminary build step and execute sphinx-build in a separate folder. rsync could be used to efficiently sync the files in the source directories and the build dir.

Another solution is to set a environment variable when building to specify the product you want to build.

You can also try setting Python’s module search path, sys.path, accordingly so that Sphinx can find them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
Just to make sure I get it right, in the first option you would use python t sync file from my real source to a copy that would be located where sphinx can find it ?

About option 2 and 3, sorry but could you develop a bit more, I'm not sure I get what you suggested. Thanks !

Comment: @Antoine For the first option, you would use rsync to sync the files in your source directories and the build directory. This would create a copy of your source files in a separate folder that Sphinx can find.
For the second option, you can set an environment variable when building to specify the product you want to build. This will tell Sphinx which product to build and where to find it.
For the third option, you can try setting Python’s module search path, sys.path, accordingly so that Sphinx can find them.

Comment: This answer and the comment looks like a copy-paste from ChatGPT

Comment: The answer only provides vague untested "maybe try this" suggestions. There is no evidence that any of them would actually solve the problem. There is no new useful information in the comment, whích to me indicates that you don't know what you are talking about.